# Starcraft 2: Custom achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

I thought I'd be sneaky and try getting the custom achievements playing "the fastest map possible". Just beat 7 insane AIs in FFA, but didn't get the "Insane FFA" achievement... why not? Does it have to be done on a Blizzard map?

Comment: That would be to easy to create a map where all the AI get no minerals and you have the whole supply. You actually have to ACHIEVE the achievement.

Comment: @Tricky: K, but that still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Thats why i made it a comment. I don't have an answer, just a theory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe that it does have to be a blizzard sponsored map.  Easiest way to get it in this case is to play on Lava Flow as terran.  As soon as the game starts, load your scvs into your command center and fly to one of the islands.  Get an engineering bay pretty soon, and start to pump out turrents along the edges, and go strait to battle cruisers.  Soon there will only be one AI left, and you should have close to 20 cruisers, so you should be able to steamroll.

Comment: Yup, achievements can only be earned on Blizzard-published maps.

Comment: Not only that, but the games have to be created from the "Multiplayer" screen of Battle.net, and not a custom-game from the single player screen.

Comment: Damn...that was hard. Took me 4 or 5 tries, and BCs didn't work. Zerg kept mind controlling them, and they built a ton of devourers..err.. corrupters? Finally did it with marines/marauders/reapers/medivacs.. last player was Protoss that time. He had a wad of Colossi too..that scared me! Good thing most were fakes. Got 4 achievements at once out of it though :D (All the FFAs)

Comment: I can't remember the map I did it on (the dark grey map with the bases separated by chasms, kinda star-shaped), but I pulled it off, first try, with terrans. If you pick a map with a raised start, and a small ramp, you can depot/bunker/tank down pretty much everything early, and they'll get bored and kill each other, rather than kill your defenses. Don't expand early, you'll never hold it. I went BC's and that worked pretty well for me. The comp winner was heavy protoss ground, and that was an easy game over, though the early defense was tight a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

I developed my own way to do this. First I tried using just one base on abyss and walling off with loads of tanks and turrets but I always ran out of money repairing my tanks. So next I tried walling off at the wide choke after the natural. Just build 2 bunkers and rax there and then build 3 planetary fortresses to seal the choke ASAP. Build a bunch of tanks and turrets and no one can get in. The AIs will pretty much destroy each other and then you can just build a nice air force and destroy whats left. Took me about an hour but this method should work faster than that as I played very timidly.

Oh and I set all AIs to terran.

Answer (score 1):

Battlecruisers work

Like Austen said, take one of the islands and mass battlecruisers with turrets surrounding island

Only use sweeps to scout players, don't send our units to scout or else you'll draw attention

Then, get one medivac and send scvs to the other island to mine vespene safely

Get Yamato, and pwnt, use orbital command for detection or get a raven

Deny Expos and demolish tech (so they can't get vikings, corruptors, or voids/phoenix/carriers depending on the race)

Comment: There is not really anything new added here, this should maybe just have been a comment on Austens answer.